# Implementing a VoIP server in DOTNET

Tags: c#, asp.net, voip, viber

I have a requirement to develop a VoIP Server (Viber like App). The client software has to be implemented on Android and the server software has to be implemented on .NET.So ,basically, the setup will consist of a server app running on a PC and a wireless access point allowing the clients (Android phones) to connect to the server.Some of the functions I will need for the server side:

1. Voice transmission
2. Instant Messaging.

Can anyone help me to implement such a server in .Net?

Comment: What you ask is too broad. Anyway, you can start by using any SIP framework out there. For Android - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html. For the .NET server - http://www.independentsoft.de/sip/index.html, maybe.

Comment: Indeed this question is very broad and the answer would be very very long.

Answer (score 1):

How much you want to do and what does the server have to do?

The MOST common approach these days is SIP (which is where "know how to read" comes in - that is a public spec, google, RFC, start going, quite long). The good thing is - SIP does not deal with audio at all on the server ;) See, unless you make a audio playback of some sort, noone wants to talk to the server. When I use my phone system, I talk to SOMEONE; not to the server.

SIP deals with SESSION INITIATION - it is a control protocol. The actual audio etc. streams are done via RTP & RTSP - again public protocols, have fun reading (and seriously, they are complex). Unless you NEED the audio streams on the server (recording etc.) there is NO need for the server even to see them - SIP is perfectly fine setting up sessions between two clients directly. SIP is done by MOST (by far) VOIP today. You may use a predefined library. Otherwise you are in a world of quite a lot of debugging, sorry ;)

Comment: We can do without the editorializing.

Comment: And I can do without you changing the meaning of my answer, really. Corecting mistakes is good, insults, too, but here you changed the MEANING = very poor judgement and terrible editing.